# Authentication type differences in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, authentication, system-tables

I want to know what is the difference between authentication types(NONE, WINDOWS, INSTANCE) in 
`sys.database_principals` table.
I can't find clear explanation in documentation.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`instance` means this is a sql login, while `windows` means this is Windows login, and `none` means it does not need authentication (such as database role).

BTW, the two columns are in `sys.database_principals`

Comment: Thanks, what about authentication type 2 (=database)